# Is SQLite read/write possible across react native, iOS and android?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to find one solution to make different part of my project communicate. The project is initialized by the react native cli, then I have made some modifications in the native android part, as well as the native iOS part.

**Right now my project looks something like this**
[image]

I need the inner react native part to share some information with the outer native iOS / android app. For example, my iOS extension needs to know whether the user is logged into the react native part of the app, so somehow they need to share this information. I also need a way of storing data no matter what. Up until now now I have been using RNCs' async storage, it stores data nicely from within the react native part, and are able to read it again from within there. I have not been able to read that data from either the main iOS app, the iOS ext or the MainActivity (android).

So I was considering a unified communication technology, and SQLite came to my mind, as I know SQLite is easily supported on android both with kotlin and java, I have also read that it works on iOS and that there should be reactnative support for it as well.

**I'm aiming for something like this**
[image]

I hope someone here with some more knowledge than me can explain whether this is even possible at all? Are the different app parts contain and restricted to read/write from a shared database? Or would this eventually work?

Further more, I am very open for suggestions. I have read a lot up on react natives documentation about sharing information between JavaScrip and native device code. It seems more easy to pass data to JavaScript from native code, than vice versa. Also it seems different on iOS than android, which is why a unified method would be a bit more convenient.

Comment: any update on this? were you able to do it? if so how?

Comment: sorry no update on this no. I ended up going with a completely different solution, read/write json to a shared file within the app group from both native and react-native code. Though I would have preferred a real database, but this was sufficient to share a few tokens.

Comment: I got a solution. was using https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage package.  We ended up copying SQLitePluginPackage.java into java code and made a SQLite singleton class to access in java and also exposed that same instance to react native as well.